# ggplot2 multiple regression lines with different type of lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot that has 6 regression lines. I have control and sample data, both of which are split by region. I am hoping to have one color per region which equates to two lines of the same color. However, I want one of those lines to be dashed and the other solid. Is this possible with geom_smooth? For example on the graph below I want CHEAD and MWHEAD to have the same color line with one solid and one dashed, and so on for the other regions. Here is my current code for this plot:

```
qplot(data=pattern,x=log10(ADD),y=Score,
    color=RegionPig, shape=Pig,  size=0.2) +
geom_smooth(method="lm", size = 1) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=8)) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=8)) + 
xlab("log10(Accumulated Degree Days)") + 
ylab("Region Scores") +  
scale_size(range = c(3,4)) + theme_grey(base_size = 25)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: You can create a Region variable first, containing `C` or `MW`, then use `color = Region, lty = Pig` in your aesthetics.